# Github ask for username & password after configuring ssh

Tags: git, github, push, ssh-keys

I have Created **SSH keygen** and Just add the Public Key to My Github Account.

When I am pushing My local Saved State to Github Repo.It ask for UserName & Password
again.

[image: 1]

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well that's likely because you still have the remote set to a `https://github.com/` URL, instead of a `git@github.com:` URI.

Comment: But From the last line you can see `username` has been Successfully authenticated

Comment: Wait, so what's wrong? Are you not getting access? Also try to go down this list of options : https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey

Comment: It Works Good.Thanks For you'r valuable input in `permission denied public key`.@ForgetfulFellow